# Putting a project on GitHub, unclear on changing to working directory

Tags: git, github

I am trying to put a few of my projects on GitHub and I have created the repositories and installed the Git command line already. There is a great read on GitHub on how to add a project using the command line. I understand how to execute most of the steps, however I am not clear on one step(I think it's the wording that's getting me). The third step says to change the current working directory to your local project. In other words, does this mean that I need to navigate to the folder that my project is in? For example, if my project is in Documents > Bootstrap cover layout how can I add this to my repository? 
I have this command  : `$ cd Documents/Bootstrap cover layout`
For some reason this is the only step that seems to be giving me trouble, otherwise everything is pretty straight forward. Even the tutorials I have watched do not seem to make this clear. I am still fairly new to Git and GitHub so clearing this up would be a great help!

Comment: Open a terminal window ... cd into dir where your project lives

Comment: Not sure of your operating system... do you need to put quotes around the folder name with spaces in it? e.g. cd Documents/"Bootstrap cover layout"

Comment: Try the quotes, or escape it with slashes as jafergas recommends. Failing that, please include the actual error message so we can better understand what's going on.

Comment: @CL01 Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type this in command prompt to go to the directory where your project is.

```
cd %userprofile%\Documents\Bootstrap cover layout
```

Then push project files to GitHub.

```
git init
git remote add origin {.git repo url here}
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

The current working directory is the directory which you are currently exploring (i.e., the one whose contents are shown when you type `ls`, or the one that is shown when you type `pwd`). In other words, you need to do `cd Documents/Bootstrap\ cover\ layout` for Linux or `cd Documents\"Bootstrap cover layout"` for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Type `cd Documents/Boo` and press TAB, it will be autocompleted...